# Cmake 3.10.2 gives an error when i install opencv contrib

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I use Visual Studio 2017 and Opencv 3.4 and Cmake 3.10.2. I want to add new module in opencv. Selected source code and selected build directory by me. When i click on "Configure" button, it throws this error.

> "Cmake error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (ocv_define_module):
>       Unknown Cmake command "ocv_define_module"."

Comment: You run `cmake` with wrong source directory. `CMakeLists.txt` for modules are not standalone. Read documentation carefully.